# Typescript - How to avoid repeating the same properties on an array of types?

Tags: typescript, figma

In the example below, I have a group of `ShadowStyle`s -> represented as type `ShadowGroup` whose items are all instances of `ShadowStyle` (the `style` property is set to inherit an external library's `ShadowEffect` type).

The thing is, there are some properties in `ShadowStyle.style` that are always the same (marked below).

My question is: how do i avoid rewriting those same properties/values for every item in the array?

```js
interface ShadowStyle {
    name: string;
    style: ShadowEffect; // type inherited from lib
}

type ShadowGroup = Array<MotifShadowStyle>;

const MyShadowGroup: ShadowGroup = [
    {
        name: 'Large',
        style: {
            type: 'DROP_SHADOW', // same for all items
            visible: true, // same for all items
            blendMode: 'NORMAL', // same for all items
            color: {
                r: 0,
                g: 0,
                b: 0,
                a: 0.14,
            },
            offset: {
                x: 0,
                y: 8,
            },
            radius: 10,
            spread: 1,
        },
    },
    {
        name: 'Medium',
       //...
    }
];
```

Answer (score 2):

define a common styles variable then reuse it by spread operator:

```
const commonDefaultStyles = {
  type: 'DROP_SHADOW', // same for all items
  visible: true, // same for all items
  blendMode: 'NORMAL' // same for all items
}


const MyShadowGroup: ShadowGroup = [
    {
        name: 'Large',
        style: {
            ... commonDefaultStyles,
            color: {
                r: 0,
                g: 0,
                b: 0,
                a: 0.14,
            },
            offset: {
                x: 0,
                y: 8,
            },
            radius: 10,
            spread: 1,
        },
    },
    {
        name: 'Medium',
       //...
    }
];
```

Reference to spread operator:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: Tried that; but TS complains because the `ShadowEffect` type supplied to the `style` key doesn't seem to "know" the result of the spread object. I'd have thought it would have been able to see that the commonDefaultStyles object has the right structure?